# "Prism.Unity 6.3.0 is not compatible with monoandroid81"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, unity-container, prism

I am trying to add Prism to my Xamarin Forms app. Following [this video by Brian Lagunas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hmH3hG28y00), I am attempting to add Prism.Unity to all of my projects (.NET Standard, Droid, iOS, and UWP). However, I am getting these errors. Does the latest version of Prism.Unity not support the latest versions for Android and iOS?

> NU1202: Package Prism.Unity 6.3.0 is not compatible with xamarinios10
>   (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0). Package Prism.Unity 6.3.0 supports:
>     - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
>     - uap10.0 (UAP,Version=v10.0) NU1202: Package Prism.Unity 6.3.0 is not
>    compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0) / win.
>   Package Prism.Unity 6.3.0 supports:
>     - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
>     - uap10.0 (UAP,Version=v10.0) NU1202: Package Prism.Unity 6.3.0 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0) / win-x64.
>   Package Prism.Unity 6.3.0 supports:
>     - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
>     - uap10.0 (UAP,Version=v10.0) NU1202: Package Prism.Unity 6.3.0 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0) / win-x86.
>   Package Prism.Unity 6.3.0 supports:
>     - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
>     - uap10.0 (UAP,Version=v10.0)
>
> NU1202: Package Prism.Unity 6.3.0 is not compatible with monoandroid81
>   (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1). Package Prism.Unity 6.3.0 supports:
>     - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
>     - uap10.0 (UAP,Version=v10.0)

I would appreciate any help! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the latest version of Prism for Xamarin Forms is 7.0 and there is a 7.1 preview. Prism 7 was updated for netstandard support and has a large number of changes that make developing apps a lot easier. Here are some blog articles to help you with Prism 7

- [Prism 7.0 - preview 3](https://dansiegel.net/post/2017/10/13/prism-for-xamarin-forms-preview-3)
- [Upgrading to Prism 7.0](https://xamgirl.com/updating-prism-7-0-xamarin-forms/)
- [Prism 7.1 - preview 1](https://dansiegel.net/post/2018/04/02/prism-7-1-preview-1)

Second you're installing the wrong package. You need to install one of the following:

- [Prism.Autofac.Forms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Autofac.Forms/)
- [Prism.DryIoc.Forms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.DryIoc.Forms/)
- [Prism.Unity.Forms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Unity.Forms/)

You can read more on the supported containers in this [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43664455/which-ioc-container-is-better-with-prism-forms/43686750#43686750).

Comment: Thank you. I had added `Prism.Unity` as in a tutorial by Brian Lagunas, but obviously that wasn't right for my project. It took a few attempts at uninstalling and reinstalling NuGet packages, but my solution is building now. Thanks!

Comment: if Brian was referencing Prism.Unity it must have been for the initial release of Prism for Xamarin Forms... It was quickly discovered that a separate package was required due to the need to support native UWP and UWP with Xamarin Forms.